# I want mortgage in currency format, but in my program instead of "$" sign it is giving me "? ' sign

Tags: java

```java
package calProject;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final byte MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;
        final byte PERCENT = 100;
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Principal: ");
        int principal = scanner.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Annual Interest Rate: ");
        float annualInterest = scanner.nextFloat();
        float monthlyInterest = annualInterest / PERCENT / MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
        
        System.out.print("Period (Years): ");
        byte years = scanner.nextByte();
        int numberOfPayments = years * MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
        
        double mortgage = principal
                      * (monthlyInterest * Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments))
                      / (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest,  numberOfPayments)-1);
        
        String mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mortgage);
        System.out.println("Mortgage: " + mortgageFormatted);
    }

}
```

OutPut:

Principal: 100000
Annual Interest Rate: 3.92
Period (Years): 30
Mortgage: ?472.81

Comment: What is your computer's locale setting? When you use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mortgage)`, why do you expect it to interpret the `mortgage` amount as a number of *dollars*, rather than, say, euros, or pounds sterling, or pesos, or drachmas?

Comment: What's the default locale of your system? I assume it isn't the US one so try `getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)` instead.

Comment: And does your terminal support UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, a `Locale` may need to be specified explicitly to get necessary currency sign:

```java
String mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(mortgage);
System.out.println("Mortgage dollar: " + mortgageFormatted);    
        
mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK).format(mortgage);
System.out.println("Mortgage pounds: " + mortgageFormatted);    
        
mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN).format(mortgage);
System.out.println("Mortgage yen: " + mortgageFormatted); 
        
mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format(mortgage);
System.out.println("Mortgage euro: " + mortgageFormatted);
```

Output:

```
Mortgage dollar: $7,164.31
Mortgage pounds: £7,164.31
Mortgage yen: ￥7,164
Mortgage euro: 7.164,31 €
```